# Error occured when importing library in main.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, gulp

I'm using gulp to pack js. Also I wanna using other libraries like `materializecss`. So I'm just importing it in my `main.js`. But after builing gulp I faced an error:

> events.js:165
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

**main.js**

```
import "materialize-css";
const Vue = require("vue");
const $ = require("jquery");

const v = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ready: function () {
        this.loadData();
    },
    data: {
        message: 'Hfssfsfello Vue.13js!',
        serverData: null
    },
    methods: {
        loadData: function (viewerUserId, posterUserId) {
            const that = this;

            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                url: window.ServerUrl + "/Home/GetData",
                method: "GET",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    that.$data.serverData = response;
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("Oops");
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**gulpfile**

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var minify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const watchify = require('watchify');
const fsPath = require('fs-path');

var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var es2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .filter(function (file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
        });
}

const paths = [
    process.env.INIT_CWD + '\\ViewModels\\home',
    process.env.INIT_CWD + '\\ViewModels\\home\\components',
    process.env.INIT_CWD + '\\ViewModels\\common\\components'
];

function watchFolder(input, output) {
    var b = browserify({
        entries: [input],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {},
        plugin: [watchify],
        basedir: process.env.INIT_CWD,
        paths: paths
    });

    function bundle() {
        b.bundle()
            .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
            .pipe(minify())
              .on('error', gutil.log)
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(output));

        gutil.log("Bundle rebuilt!");
    }
    b.on('update', bundle);
    bundle();
}

function compileJS(input, output) {
    // set up the browserify instance on a task basis
    var b = browserify({
        debug: true,
        entries: [input],
        basedir: process.env.INIT_CWD,
        paths: paths
    });

    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe(babel({ compact: false, presets: ['es2015'] }))
        // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
        .pipe(minify())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        //.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(output));
}

const scriptsPath = 'ViewModels';

gulp.task('build', function () {
    var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);
    gutil.log(folders);
    folders.map(function (folder) {
        compileJS(scriptsPath + "//" + folder + "//main.js", "Scripts//app//" + folder);
    });
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);
    gutil.log(folders);
    folders.map(function (folder) {
        watchFolder(scriptsPath + "//" + folder + "//main.js", "Scripts//app//" + folder);
    });

});
```

By the way, I'm very new to vue js framework and I'm trying to integrate this framework with `ASP .NET MVC`. And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'd be very appreciated if somebody answers me.

Comment: use `require` instead of `import` for the first line ?

Comment: @V.Sambor and how do I use lib then?

Comment: I mean instead of `import "materialize-css";` try `require("materialize-css")`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely not an answer, but I refused to use gulp. Instead I've installed webpack. Now it's alright!